# Capital ẞ in LaTeX/XeTeX/lualatex/whatever

Tags: fonts, fontspec, unicode

I am trying to get a ẞ in my LaTeX document. How can I do this? I already tried:

- Using other fonts: dejavu and libertine
- Using `\MakeUppercase{ß}`, which sometimes produces nothing, sometimes produces "SS"
- Using `{\sc ß}`, which sometimes produces nothing, sometimes produces "SS"
- Using XeTeX and lualatex: Just leaves out ẞ and warns about the Glyph that it could not find
- Using `\symbol{"1E9E}`, which also produces nothing

How can I do this?

Comment: A capital 'ß' _is_ 'SS' (see Unicode specs, for example).

Comment: Does your font support the capital-ß? ConTeXt and LuaLaTeX print any unicode-character, if it is in the font. XeTeX should do the same.

Comment: Just for completeness it should be added that the capital ß is not a SS anymore. In Germany at least https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_ẞ

Comment: Is there any solution for pdflatex as well?

Comment: Sorry, but from history the ß is an sz-ligature and so is the uppercase.
That is, uppercase ß is more likely SZ than SS because the vocal before the SZ is a long one. Wirting uppercase ß as SS always implies that the vocal before is a short one. Thus, the pronounciation is totally different.

Comment: 1) that is not really an answer to the question. 2) you are wrong, e.g. [Germanspelling says to use SS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gro%C3%9Fes_%C3%9F#Versalien_ohne_gro%C3%9Fes_%C3%9F) since 1996. (one can of course discuss if the _neue deutsche Rechtschreibung_ from 1996 was good overall...)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What do you need it for?

Answer (score 16):

The easiest solution, if you're sure that all the fonts you use in the document have the character U+1E9E LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S, is to say

```
\uccode`ß="1E9E
```

Otherwise, you need to provide substitutes; here's an example with Linux Libertine and Latin Modern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

%% simplistic solution
%\uccode`ß="1E9E

%% solution with substitutions
\newunicodechar{ß}{\ss}
\renewcommand{\SS}{\iffontchar\font"1E9E \symbol{"1E9E}\else SS\fi}

\newfontfamily{\lmr}[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  SmallCapsFont=Latin Modern Roman Caps,
]{Latin Modern Roman}


\begin{document}
\Huge
groß \MakeUppercase{groß}
\scshape Groß \MakeUppercase{Groß}

\lmr
groß \MakeUppercase{groß}
\scshape Groß \MakeUppercase{Groß}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Linux Libertine has it. Run it with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\uccode`ß="1E9E
\begin{document}
\Huge
groß \MakeUppercase{groß}
\scshape Groß \MakeUppercase{Gro\char"1E9E}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Lualatex, the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{DejaVu Sans}
```

Comment: DejaVu is one of the fonts that include capital-ß. According to Wikipedia, there are a few more that you might have access to. Windows 7: Times New Roman, Arial, Courier New, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe UI, Segoe UI Light, Segoe UI Semibold.
Windows 8: see Windows 7, plus Cambria, Calibri, Candara, Consolas, Constantia and Corbel
Mac OS X: Geneva
Free fonts: DejaVu-Paket, Linux Libertine and Linux Biolinum, Junicode If your favourite font does not include capital-ß, you can map it in from a font that has it. By the way, the DajaVu-Package is compatible with classic LaTeX too.

Answer (score 1):

It's more or less everywhere now.

Just looking at five fonts at random:

[image: Five at random]

Answer (score 0):

The expl3 language provides a function [`tl_upper_case:nn {language} {input}`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#HD.1012), where the *language* code `de-alt` converts ß to a *großes Eszett*.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\toUpper[1]{\tl_upper_case:nn{de-alt}{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\toUpper{Frauenfußball}

\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus font sample]

[In newer systems,](https://www.texdev.net/2020/01/15/case-changing-in-expl3) you could instead use `\text_uppercase:nn`.  As of 2020, the documentation says that the second argument should be “a BCP 47 string,” but in fact only `de-alt` works, and `de-DE-1996` as specified in the RFC does not.  With the newer interfaces, you would therefore write:

```
\text_uppercase:nn {de-alt}{\text_expand:n{#1}}
```

[The expl3 documentation claims](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#HD.495) that you can define your own mapping with `\char_set_uccode:nn`, but when I tested this with

```
\char_set_uccode:nn {`ß} {`ẞ}
```

within the same TeX group as a `\tl_upper_case:n` or `text_uppercase:n`, it still mapped ß to SS.