# Uppercase ß support in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, german

The German languages adds the uppercase form of the versal `ß` to it's alphabet now and I was wondering, how this specific letter is supported in LaTeX as well as what types of fonts provided in LaTeX can be used to print it.

Research only provides information about how to code the lowercase `ß` and not much else.

Is it actually supported yet or does it need to be implemented?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171401/capital-%E1%BA%9E-in-latex-xetex-lualatex-whatever

Comment: I know of no legacy LaTeX font (usable with `pdflatex`) that supports the glyph. Maybe some font will be updated now that the glyph has been accepted, but don't be expecting it.