# Display ß in small caps

Tags: koma-script, unicode, characters, small-caps, german

When I use ß in headings - which I want to be in small caps - it gets replaced by a double S. Is there a way to still have a ß there, which is also the same height as the other letters?

Just to clarify: I've modified the `\sectionlinesformat` this way so that I get small caps in the headers while displaying the text normal in the toc.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[osf]{newpxtext}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\huge\fontfamily{qpl}\selectfont\normalfont\lsstyle\scshape}
\setkomafont{section}{\large\fontfamily{qpl}\selectfont\normalfont\lsstyle\scshape}

\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{#3 \MakeLowercase{#4}}

\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\normalfont\lsstyle\scshape}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{größe}
    \section{Größe}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** I've already tried the solution from [Capital ẞ in LaTeX/XeTeX/lualatex/whatever](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171401/capital-%E1%BA%9E-in-latex-xetex-lualatex-whatever), but this didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capital ẞ in LaTeX/XeTeX/lualatex/whatever](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171401/capital-%e1%ba%9e-in-latex-xetex-lualatex-whatever)

Comment: Some typefaces do not cover all glyphs of extended latin in their fonts. From my experience, small caps is a classical contender for reduced set of glyphs.

Answer (score 2):

The expl3 language provides a function [`tl_upper_case:nn {language} {input}`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#HD.1012), where the *language* code `de-alt` converts ß to a *großes Eszett*.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\toUpper[1]{\tl_upper_case:nn{de-alt}{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\toUpper{Frauenfußball}

\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus font sample]

[In newer systems,](https://www.texdev.net/2020/01/15/case-changing-in-expl3) you could instead use `\text_uppercase:nn`.  As of 2020, the documentation says that the second argument should be “a BCP 47 string,” but in fact only `de-alt` works, and `de-DE-1996` as specified in the RFC does not.  With the newer interfaces, you would therefore write:

```
\text_uppercase:nn {de-alt}{\text_expand:n{#1}}
```

[The expl3 documentation claims](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#HD.495) that you can define your own mapping with `\char_set_uccode:nn`, but when I tested this with

```
\char_set_uccode:nn {`ß} {`ẞ}
```

within the same TeX group as a `\tl_upper_case:n` or `text_uppercase:n`, it still mapped ß to SS.

Comment: \tl_upper_case has been deprecated, the command is now named \text_uppercase:n.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! It didn’t work when I tried that, either.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Did some testing with `text_uppercase:nn` and updated with what worked and what didn’t.

Answer (score 1):

Well `ß` is in pdflatex a command, so yes you could locally redefine it. But to get a suitable size you would have to scale quite a lot and imho this looks simply bad:

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[osf]{newpxtext}

\begin{document}
{\scshape Aabc\textup{ß}abc{\upshape\fontsize{6.5pt}{6.5pt}\selectfont ß}abc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the letter in both the chapter heading and the toc changes to the specified size

Comment: @Johannes sure, As I think it is a bad idea I only try to demonstrate how bad it looks and not to implement a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a font that provides the character you are expecting. In a lot of fonts, ß is replaced by SS in small caps, because this used to be the standard replacement. Check https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gro%C3%9Fes_%C3%9F to see that only in 2008, the uppercase character was introduced to Unicode.

Comment: SS is still the "*standard* replacement". It's both specified in Unicode as the uppercase variant and in the german spelling rules ([The rule basically says](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6180#par25E3): When writing in capitals, "SS" is used. Furthermore, the capital letter "ẞ" is also allowed.)