# biblatex: capitalize ß to ẞ, not SS, in bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

I am using a `biblatex` style that capitalizes authors' last names in the bibliography (ISO960, i.e. `style=iso-authoryear`). When an author's last name includes a ß, this gets capitalized to SS, but I would prefer for it to be capitalized to ẞ instead (which the font I'm using has). Here's a small example:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8
%!TEX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[force]{test.bib}
@Unpublished{Heussner2023,
  author = {{Heußner}, Ludwig},
  note   = {Lecture Notes},
  title  = {Angewandte Nationalökonomologie},
  month  = aug,
  year   = {2023},
  day    = {17},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XCharter}
\begin{document}
\textcite{Heussner2023} is a very interesting read.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

How can I tell biblatex that ß should become ẞ, not SS?

**EDIT:** [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171401/capital-ẞ-in-latex-xetex-lualatex-whatever](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171401/capital-%E1%BA%9E-in-latex-xetex-lualatex-whatever) does not answer this question.

Comment: Egreg's answer works also in your case. Just add `\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ß}{\ss}
\renewcommand{\SS}{\iffontchar\font"1E9E \symbol{"1E9E}\else SS\fi}` to your preamble

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why do you encase `Heußner` in the `author` field in curly braces?

Comment: @DG' the answer is quite outdated, support for uppercasing has changed a lot in the last years.

Comment: @DG' thanks for the link, and the code snippet; unfortunately, neither works.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know, but the MWE worked with that solution. Good thing you gave an more up-to-date answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use babel and (n)german you can set the casing to eszett:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[force]{testss.bib}
@Unpublished{Heussner2023,
  author = {{Heußner}, Ludwig},
  note   = {Lecture Notes},
  title  = {Angewandte Nationalökonomologie},
  month  = aug,
  year   = {2023},
  day    = {17},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelprovide[casing=eszett]{ngerman}
\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testss.bib}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XCharter}
\begin{document}
\textcite{Heussner2023} is a very interesting read. 

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

(Without babel you can do something similar, but I assume that you want to set the language ...)

Without babel you can add a mapping directive:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareUppercaseMapping{"00DF}{\char"1E9E}

\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testss.bib}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XCharter}
\begin{document}
\textcite{Heussner2023} is a very interesting read. 

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike! I'm writing in English, and therefore I'm not using babel (nor polyglossia).

Comment: english doesn't know this casing variant, but I added an edit for this case.

Comment: Excellent, thanks again.